# How do I prove relations of two CTL formulas?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, formal-methods, linear-temporal-logic, computation-tree-logic

If I have two CTL equations, how do I prove they're equivalent or that one implies the other?

What's the general approach? Disproving is obvious, but I am unable to figure out how to prove the equivalence of the two or an implication

Comment: You could use a proof system (e.g. [Pnueli & Kesten's paper in CONCUR 2002](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45694-5_2) for the richer CTL${}^*$) or ask a model checker such as [nuSMV](https://nusmv.fbk.eu/).